# How to install deb packages which are stored in another manually created deb package?

Tags: debian, package-management, deb

I want to create my own deb package for my application that will be deployed on multiple devices that don't have an internet connection. Therefore I put the application dependency files (downloaded as a deb file) in my application deb package. Before or after installing my application deb package, I should install dependencies.

How can I install dependencies which are stored in my packages?

Comment: A better approach would be a local repository with all the packages.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian-format packages can’t control the installation of other packages except using dependencies in their own control files, which effectively means that dependency resolution has to be performed externally.

In your scenario, the practical consequences of this are that:

- your package can include other `.deb` files, but it can’t install them;
- your package can’t depend on any of those included `.deb` files.

I recommend shipping all the required packages in a tarball, and instructing users to extract that and install all the resulting packages; see [the LibreOffice downloads](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/?type=deb-x86_64) for an example of this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't I use `preinst` or `postinst` scripts to do that?

Comment: No, they can’t invoke `dpkg` to install or remove packages, or any other tool relying on `dpkg` to do so.